# How to make value in func to global constant in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How do I go about setting the long and latitude value (both which display a when app runs) to a global constant?  The values are currently

```
String(format: "4.4f", latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
```

and

```
String(format: "4.4f", latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
```

I want to make these a global constant like `userlatitude` and `userlongitude` which can be accessed outside the function. Do I have to return someHope that makes sense.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    var latestLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation

    latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    longitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can store Locations to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
//First Convert it to NSNumber.
let lat : NSNumber = NSNumber(double: Location.latitude)
let lng : NSNumber = NSNumber(double: Location.longitude)

//Store it into Dictionary
let locationDict = ["lat": lat, "lng": lng]

//Store that Dictionary into NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationDict, forKey: "Location")
```

After that you can access it this way anywhere you want:

```
//Access that stored Values
let userLoc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Location") as! [String : NSNumber]

//Get user location from that Dictionary
let userLat = userLoc["lat"]
let userLng = userLoc["lng"]

var Annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

Annotation.coordinate.latitude = userLat as! CLLocationDegrees  //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
Annotation.coordinate.longitude = userLng as! CLLocationDegrees //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
```

Comment: Hi @Dharmesh Kheni, when I access the variable in the view did load method on the initial screen, it says that there is  "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"..  Is it saving after the screen is loaded, causing a nil?  How do I fix this?

Comment: @JoshO'Connor, Please study about Optional and Unwrap in Swift.

Comment: Check this sample project: https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Show-User-Location-With-Pin

Comment: @Renish, I have been studying about optional and unwrap, but at a block... clearly you dont have an answer besides to tell me to study.. Good response.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define your Variable Below of import statement. Something Like,

   ```
   import UIKit

   let latitude = 4.0

   // Do Stuff - This Variable access in Any class. Thanx Swift....
   ```
2. Another solution is put your value in `.plist/NSUser` Default and access in every class(Where should you wish to use) using appropriate key.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be that you store the values as NSUserDefaults, which gives you access to the values when you need it. try this link for more information http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/